# How to detect KEYCODE_DEL on soft keyboard?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

`mMessageComposeUsernames` is a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` and I want to delete space (if it is last char of my `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`) or delete a single word (to the last `" "`, if it is not).

Code:

```
mMessageComposeUsernames.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                String string = mMessageComposeUsernames.getText().toString();
                if (!string.substring(string.length() - 1).equals(" ")) {
                    if (string.contains(" ")) {
                        string = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(" "));
                    } else {
                        string = "";
                    }
                }
                Log.i("string", string);
                mMessageComposeUsernames.setText(string);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I get nothing in `Logs`, so I think `onKey` isn't executed... How can I do what I want when `KEYCODE_DEL` is 'pressed' on soft keyboard? :)

Comment: use to trim() method.

Comment: I want to delete the whole word if on the last index there is something else than spacebar... E.g. "aaa bbb " should be converted to "aaa bbb", but "aaa bbb" should be converted to "aaa " after `KEYCODE_DEL`. So your advise isn't helpful... How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can you to below code for implement to your idea:

```
 String yourstring1 = YourString.trim();
 if(!YourString.equals(yourstring1)){
     YourString = YourString.replace(YourString.substring(str.length()-1), "");
 }
```